# Windows: Start exe from a batch file and handle popup dialogs started by the exe

Tags: windows, powershell, batch-file, cmd

I want to automate the installation of a component under windows 7. When I call the setup.exe from within a batch file, a dialog box opens asking me whether I really want to install the component. Since I want to automate the whole process, I need a way to automatically answer this dialog with "yes", or prevent the dialog from popping up in a way that doesn't cancel the setup.

How can I do that?

Comment: depend on the exe type you have, some of them might be installed with msiexec, some not, another option(not so stable) is to use Wshell.SendKeys to answer the dialog box, `$wshell = New-Object -ComObject wscript.shell; $wshell.SendKeys('{ENTER}')`

Comment: Your $Wshell.SendKeys approach seems to point to the right direction, thanks. However, I have never heard of it.
Could you give me a short windows cmd example, assuming that my process is called "setup.exe" and opens a dialog which offers "install" or "repair" option from which I have to select?

Comment: Cannot be done in a pure batch file.  You will need to use vbscript, jscript or powershell. A lot of people use a program like AutoHotkey or AutoIt.

Comment: You don't say what kind of "component" you are installing, but if this dialog is because you're installing unsigned drivers, then the dialog is not designed to be bypassed. Other than that, you should ask the author/vendor of the component you are installing for instructions on how to install it silently. This is not really a programming question.